# How to get time of Fibonacci recursion

Tags: java, recursion, fibonacci

I have an task, they give to me an recursion fibonacci algoritm and ask to return a time. I done it with .SystemCurrentMilis and i post my code below, but the testers said that its takes to long to count time, so i think i must give them some teoretic time, because execute function and get time is too long. Hope on yours help guys. How to make function timetocompute work faster on whatever n coming.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Fibonacci {

public BigDecimal timeToComputeRecursiveFibonacci(int n) {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    recursive(n);
    long finishTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long tempTime = finishTime - startTime;
    BigDecimal usedTime = BigDecimal.valueOf(tempTime);
    return usedTime;
}


public BigInteger recursive(int n) { 
    if (n <= 1)
        return BigInteger.valueOf(n);
    return recursive(n - 1).add(recursive(n - 2));
}
```

}

Comment: Dynamic programming is the way to go forward! Think what happens when n = 3 and n= 4, how many times you call recursiveF method?

Comment: I was thinking on that topic and i think that if cames n =  3 method calls 1 time more than n. I hope i right but i dont understand how its help me. I was found in web that its O(2^n) but how its return time i dont understand at all.

Comment: I should warn you that, if your instructor finds this, you could face accusations of plagiarism.  You should instead create a [**Minimal**, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem without giving away too much of your assignment solution.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking for here. You don't seem to be asking for a faster `recursive(n)` -- are you asking for a more accurate measurement of its execution time? Something that gets the current time in milliseconds faster than `System.currentTimeMillis()`? Can you provide a program that returns a number that's too big, along with an indication of what you consider an acceptable size?

Answer (score -1):

I have created some measurements for the recursive function. If you think about it, if you can measure `recursive(n)` then `recursive(n+1)` would be almost 2 times slower, as it needs to calculate the function for n, and n-1 as well.

- nth - ms
- 30 - 25
- 31 - 43
- 32 - 70
- 33 - 113
- 34 - 196
- 35 - 301
- 36 - 513
- 37 - 926
- 38 - 1266
- 39 - 2210
- 40 - 3652

So you can estimate 40th number from the 30th time with 1.65^10*25, which is `1.65^m*time(n)`. This can be converted to years. I would try to do something like this.